# Python - Combine all items in a list into a string

Tags: python

Is there a way to combine all items in a list into one string?

```
    print(isbnl)# str(isbnl).strip('[]'))
```

Comment: You mean `str.join()`? e.g. `', '.join(isbnl)`? You forgot to specify what output you'd expect. Or use `print(*isbnl, sep=', ')`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two options:

If the items in your list are already strings:

```
list_of_strings = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'] # give a list of strings

new_string = "".join(list_of_strings)   # join them into a new string
```

If the items in your list are not ALL strings, you can must turn them into strings first:

```
list_of_nonstrings = [1.83, some_object, 4, 'abc'] # given a list of mixed types

# construct new list of strings for join function
list_of_strings = [str(thing) for thing in list_of_nonstrings]

new_string = "".join(list_0f_strings) # join into new string, just like before
```

Now you may print or manipulate `new_string` however you need to.